# Wait for click event in a for loop

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-dialog

I have an array of images like this:

```
int[] fruitList = new int[] {
      R.drawable.apple,
      R.drawable.orange,
      R.drawable.bannana
};
```

and an ImageView. For every fruit i want to a) populate the ImageView b) wait for click to open a Dialog (Choose fruit name and do something ...) and repeat for next fruit.

I thought of a for loop but doesn't make sense. I need to wait for the click before going to the next fruit.

Any ideas ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Hold an index for your position along the fruitList
2. Set an [onClickListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener) on the Image View.
3. Create a Dialog in the onClickListener
4. [Subscribe any clicks in the dialog](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html#setButton(int,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener)), and in that subscription change the fruit by incrementing your index (maybe `% fruitList.size`?)
5. In the onClickListener launch the dialog

The key difference between app development and smaller programs is that apps are all event based. A for loop isn't suited for this kind of task.

Comment: Thanks man. I ended doing what you said and added an interface and a listener in onDismiss of the dialog to increment the index of the array.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Carousel view for it. You can use following repositories for it. Choose what you want

- https://github.com/sayyam/carouselview
- https://github.com/Azoft/CarouselLayoutManager
- https://android-arsenal.com/tag/154
- https://medium.com/@lobothijau/create-carousel-easily-in-android-app-with-carouselview-6cbf5ef500a9

Comment: This looks like a gallery. I want to display one image at a time, maybe some animation and change it after the AlertDialog has closed